# Somar valores de linhas dinâmicas automaticamente

Tags: jquery

Conforme o exemplo abaixo, estou tentando somar os valor das linhas `Qtde Transferir`, que são geradas dinamicamente conforme o resultado do banco, subtrair do valor digitado no campo `Quantidade a Transferir` e exibir a diferença no campo `Falta`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Montei o código abaixo, usando alguns exemplos que encontrei, ele somou as linhas dinâmicas, mas preciso primeiro digitar os valores nas linhas e por ultimo a `Quantidade a Transferir` para calcular a `Falta`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#qtde_entrada").on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
     var total = 0;
     $('.input').each(function(){
       var valor = Number($(this).val());
       if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
     });
     var final = $("#qtde_entrada").val() - total;
     $("#qtde_falta").val(final);
    }
    });
});
```

Os inputs estão setados desta forma:

**Qtde a Transferir e Falta:**

```
      <tr>
          <td colspan='2'>Quantidade a Transferir:
          <input type = "number" id="qtde_entrada" name = "qtde_entrada"  min="1" max="99999" style="width: 10em;"> -
          <b>Falta: <input type = "number" id="qtde_falta" name = "qtde_falta" class="resultado" style="width: 10em;" readonly></b></td>
      </tr>
```

**Qtde Transferir (dinâmico):**

```
HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '5' name = 'qtde_trans[]' id = 'qtde_trans[]' class='input' ></td></tr>";
```

Alguma sugestão de como poderia fazer para primeiro digitar o valor total a transferir e conforme for digitado nas linhas ele ir exibindo na falta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode separar o cálculo em uma função:

```
function calc() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
      var total = 0;
      $('.input').each(function(){
        var valor = Number($(this).val());
        if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
      });
      var final = $("#qtde_entrada").val() - total;
      $("#qtde_falta").val(final);
    }
}
```

E utilizá-la no evento `change` tanto do `#qtde_entrada` quanto dos campos dinâmicos:

```
$('#qtde_entrada').on('change', calc);
$('table').on('change', '.input', calc);
```

Repare na segunda linha do código acima, a construção do `on` está diferente. Como os campos são dinâmicos, você precisa usar algo chamado de [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Isso é necessário porque quando você escuta um evento no Javascript, ele associa a função de resposta aos elementos presentes no [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction); então se temos o seguinte código:

```
`$('.input').on('change', calc);
```

A função `calc` vai ser associado ao evento `change` dos elementos `.input` presentes no momento da chamada. O que não resolveria seu problema, umas vez que esses campos são dinâmicos e podem ser inseridos na página após a execução do código acima.

Ao utilizarmos a construção:

```
$('table').on('change', '.input', calc);
```

A biblioteca jQuery vai associar o evento `change` ao elemento `table`, mas vai executar a função `calc` apenas quando o `change` ocorrer nos elementos `.input`. Isso ocorre devido ao [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing), que faz com que ao ocorrer um evento em um elemento, ele (o evento) é propagado até o pai mais alto a partir do elemento onde o evento foi iniciado, ou até que a propagação seja cancelada (retornando `false` ou chamando o método `stopPropagation` do evento).

Como mostra na imagem abaixo, o evento iniciou no elemento de número 3 e propagou para cima até o elemento de número 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma o evento não está mais associado apenas aos elementos que existiam na hora da associação. Os novos elementos também vão propagar o evento e a função `calc` será chamada corretamente.

Veja funcionando: https://jsfiddle.net/bdsb70rh/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Estou olhando no JSfiddle e realmente funcionou. No meu caso ainda não, mas estou revisando novamente.

Comment: @Diego Como aplicou as modificações?

Comment: Deu certo, faltou uma # na parte que mudei no var table. Obrigado pela excelente explicação e resposta. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

O código quase faz o que deseja, porém não recalcula enquanto está digitando nas linhas. Para isso basta adicioná-las ao evento de alteração.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#qtde_falta").val("? - 0.0"); // Definimos um texto inicial
});
function alteracaoValores() // Quando houver alterações, não importando qual dos campos for (das linhas ou da qtd transferir)
{
    var total = 0.0;
    $('.somatorio').each(function() // Tanto para alteração na linha superior como nas editadas...
    {
        var valor = Number($(this).val());
            if (!isNaN(valor)) total += valor;
    }
    var quant_entr = parseFloat($("#qtde_entrada").val());
    if(!isNaN(quant_entr))
    {
        var final = quant_entr - total;
            $("#qtde_falta").val(final);
    }
    else
    $("#qtde_falta").val("? - " + total); // Colocar texto quando não tiver campo quantidade a transferir preenchido.
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
      <td colspan='2'>Quantidade a Transferir:
      <input type = "number" id="qtde_entrada" name = "qtde_entrada"  min="1" max="99999" style="width: 10em;" onchange='alteracaoValores();'> -
      <b>Falta: <input type = "number" id="qtde_falta" name = "qtde_falta" class="resultado" style="width: 10em;" readonly></b></td>
</tr>
```

HTML gerado dinâmicamente:

```
HTML += "<td><input type = 'text' size = '5' name = 'qtde_trans[]' id = 'qtde_trans[]' class='input somatorio' onchange='alteracaoValores();' ></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas está dando um erro que não identifiquei porque: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

var quant_entr = parseFloat($("#qtde_entrada").val());